# PHP Laravel - Test Query Result

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

From routes.php

```
Route::post('/invoices/detail/', function()
    {

    $db = new \PDO("odbc:DRIVER={AS400 Driver}; SYSTEM=mysystem.test.com;", "myid", 
"mypasswd");

     $query  = "SELECT ILINVN, ILLINE, ILDATE, ILPROD, IDESC, ILQTY, (ILNET * ILQTY) AS 
AMOUNT FROM mydb LEFT OUTER JOIN mydb ON ILPROD = IPROD WHERE ILINVN = 
:invoice_number";


    //query system
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);

    $statement->bindValue(':invoice_number', Session::get('invoice_number'),  
  PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if($statement->execute() !== false)
    {

        //save system query results
        $results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    else
    {

        $results = array();

    }

    return View::make('invoice_detail')->with('results', $results);

})->before('auth');
```

This is from invoice_detail.blade.php  I verified the query works.  It appears the information is not making it to the view or something in the view is incorrect.

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

@if(isset($results))

 <div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="pull-left">

        <div>

        </div>

    </div>

     <div class="pull-right">

    </div>

 </div>

<div class="col-md-12">

     <h4>Tracking</h4>

    <div class="table-responsive">

         <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped">

            <tr>

                <td><p><strong>Invoice Number</strong></p></td>
                <td><p><strong>Line #</strong></p></td>
                <td><p><strong>Invoice Date</strong></p></td>
                <td><p><strong>Item</strong></p></td>
                <td><p><strong>Description</strong></p></td>
                <td><p><strong>Qty Shipped</strong></p></td>
                <td><p><strong>Ext. Amt.</strong></p></td>

            </tr>

            @foreach($results as $result)

            <tr>
                <td><p>{{ $result['ILINVN'] }}</p></td>
                <td><p>{{ $result['ILLINE'] }}</p></td>
                <td><p>{{ $result['ILDATE'] }}</p></td>
                <td><p>{{ $result['ILPROD'] }}</p></td>
                <td><p>{{ $result['IDESC'] }}</p></td>
                <td><p>{{ $result['ILQTY'] }}</p></td>
                <td><p>{{ $result['AMOUNT'] }}</p></td>             
            </tr>

            @endforeach

        </table>

    </div>

 </div>
 @endif
 @stop
```

Hope this helps.  Too me a bit to get rid of this screaming about having so much code.  lol Can't win.  Sorry the lack of information initially.  I thought it might be enough plus I was tired.  Thanks again

Comment: Please, show us the query you use to get `$results`.

Comment: The query is in the routes.php which I already did the troubleshooting there and know the query is good.  What it might be is the results not making it to the view

Comment: I asked because there's a difference in displaying single result and collection. You don't need to loop through the first one. How are you passing the `$results` to the view?

Comment: I just removed the multiple lines for all the columns in the array so it only showed one on here.  There was like 7.          return View::make('invoice_detail')->with('results', $results);

Comment: OK, you really need to show some code. Edit the post: add your route and the part of code responsible for getting the results (if you have it in separate controller). Otherwise, can't really help you.

Comment: I changed Session::get('invoice_number') to 'invoice_number' and it displays the results suddenly but of course not showing the invoice number.  I had changed to that before and it wasn't working so not sure if it was a syntax issue.  Gotta love those.  Now just have to get it to show the invoice number on the details page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm sure it's very simple but just missing it

Indeed it is ;) And what you're missing are PHP tags!

```
<?php $result->ILINVN = 'test'; ?>
```

Comment: Duhh. lol  Thanks.  But still didn't change the display and I refreshed several times.  Maybe something in the foreach as the view source on the page isn't even showing the tr lines.

Comment: I ended up changing :invoice_number
To 
$_POST[invoice_number]

Answer (score 0):

You mix array and object notation. Generally you cannot access an object as an array or an array as an object.

You cannot use

```
$result->ILINVN
```

and

```
$result['ILINVN']
```

One of them is incorrect, but it is not possible to tell which one with the code you provided.